Why doesn’t Mac terminal accept command line parameters after a cat sat on my keyboard?
I caught my cat sitting on my keyboard and now the terminal doesn't accept arguments for any command in either zsh or bash.
For example:

ls works where as ls -al gives zsh: command not found
cd works where as cd tmp gives -bash: cd tmp: command not found

I tried resetting both profiles. No joy.  What the hell has the cat done? How doe I fix this?
EDIT:  With the keyboard viewer on screen I can see the spacebar is being recognised as the option modifier. If I turn off the option modifier in keyboard shortcuts I get my spacebar back, but I've lost the option modifier.

if the space key has issue then the temporary trick is to use a tab: Press Ctrl+V then Tab to insert a tab character

This is why the terminal interprets spacebar presses as an Option key press, which is likely causing the issue with command-line arguments.
Try:

Reset Modifier Keys: Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys... and reset the settings for your keyboard. This should restore the spacebar’s functionality and the Option key’s behavior.

Check Input Sources: Ensure the correct keyboard layout is selected under System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources. Sometimes, accidental changes here can cause unexpected key behavior.

Disable Sticky Keys or Accessibility Options: If sticky keys or other accessibility features were accidentally activated, turn them off via System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard.


Now the terminal should start accepting command-line arguments as expected.
